# Footer внизу окна

Tags: html, css

Есть `footer`, который не хочет быть внизу, если контента меньше, чем высота браузера.

[image]

Знаю, что можно через

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
```

Но этот способ баженный (если уменьшать окно, то `footer` будет лезть на другие элементы)

Через `min-height` проставить высоту для `wraper 100%` тоже не вариант. Может, кто-то решал подобное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаем: [как прижать футер (подвал) к низу](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/podval-k-nizu.html).

Главное внимательно прочтите и правильно реализуйте. И вообще, [этот сайт](http://www.xiper.net/) советую всем веб-дизайнерам.